# Passing a ListBox control object to a function requiring a ListBox as argument

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, controls

I am going over all control elemtens in my form and want to passt all ListBoxes to another function.
The Code looks like this:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then

        Save (ctl)

    End If
Next ctl

Private Sub Save(list As ListBox)
    'Do something with list
End Sub
```

It gives me 424 Runtime Error, telling me that an object is needed.

When I try to use

```
Save (ctl.Object)
```

I'll get an 2455 Runtime Error.

EDIT: I also tryed casting the ctl Control Object to a ListBox Object with

```
Dim list As ListBox
Set list = ctl
```

Then it tells me the same as in my first example (Error 424)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the brackets, so:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then

        Save ctl

    End If
Next ctl
```

VBA is very fussy about brackets.

I strongly recommend that you use something other than Save as the name of your function, it is very easy to disrupt VBA.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Never got behind the brackets in vba.